# How do I use godep with testing packages

Tags: go, dependency-management

I have just started using [godep](https://github.com/tools/godep) for the first time. When I ran `godep save`, the `Godeps.json` file did not include [testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify) which is a dependency for my unit tests.

`go get -t` would see [testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify), how do I tell godep to include my test dependencies?

Comment: Just in case anyone comes around here, godep does this automatically. I just needed to run 'godep save ./...'.

Comment: Please turn your comment into an answer and accept it as the SO policy suggests

Comment: @kostix Just posted it. Will accept it as soon as SO allows me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`godep` saves test dependencies automatically. In my case, the tests were in an inner package, so I only needed to run `godep save ./...` instead of `godep save` and testify was found as expected.